# macOS - Bash script that launch 3 terminal with command as argoument

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

With a `.sh` script I need to launch 3 new terminal (iTerm on mac) with a command inside.

I've already try to use:

```
open -a iTerm /path/foo
```

And I found that `open` accept `--args` but it dosen't work. What i need to do is:

- Open 3 new terminal (using iTerm)
- Execute a specific command on the 3 new bash

There is a way to do that with `.sh` file?

Comment: duplicate of another  cummunity  https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the

Comment: the link is for ubuntu, I need for macOS